# Insert recursive/nested Object in recursive table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, recursion, ado.net

Using microsoft sql server assume the following sample table with recursive relation

```
[dbo].[IPAddress]
(
    [IPAddressID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [IP] [nchar] (15),
    [ParentID] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [IPAddressID]
)
```

I have the following nested object which has a list of same type objects

```
public class IPAddress
{
    public int IPAddressID { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public IPAddress[] Childs { get; set; }
}

var IP = new IPAddress
{
    IP = "10.0.0.0",
    Childs = new IPAddress[]
    {
        new IPAddress
        {
            IP="10.1.0.0",
            Childs = new IPAddress[]
            {
                new IPAddress{ IP="10.1.1.0" },
                new IPAddress{ IP="10.1.2.0" },
                new IPAddress{ IP="10.1.3.0" }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When insert that object, Table data should be like this:

```
IPAddressID,IP,ParentID
10,'10.0.0.0',Null
12,'10.1.0.0',10
13,'10.1.1.0',12
14,'10.1.2.0',12
15,'10.1.3.0',12
```

In my real case the base object may has 60 childs as second level, each child in the second level has 4 childs in the third level then the flat object count is 1 + 60 + (60*4) = 2461 object/row and the object has 25 property mapped to 25 colums in inhertance tables hierarchy, so what is the best way to insert that object to table using c# ado.net? may I use cte in this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. You can try calling this method by passing your `IPAddress` object. You can build an insert string with all the queries and call `ExecuteNonQuery` only once if you want to be more efficient. Be careful there's a 1000 insert limit per queries.

```
public void InsertIpAdress(IPAddress myipaddress)
{
string cs = "Put your connection string"
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);

try
{
    //Open connection
    cn.Open();

    //First we insert the parent(Use stored procedure provided if you want)
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[AddParent]", cn);
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Add parameter
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", myipaddress.IP);

    //Output parameter
    SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@Parent",SqlDbType.Int);
    output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cm.Parameters.Add(output);

    //Execute query
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Here we get parent id
    int parent = Convert.ToInt32(output.Value.ToString());

    //Then we have to add every children
    cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO YourTable (IP,ParentID) VALUES (@ip,@parent);", cn);

    //Add parent as parameter 
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parent", parent);

    foreach(IPAddress element in myipaddress.Childs)
    {
        //Add the current child ip
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", element.IP);

        //Execute command
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //Close connection
    cn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //You can handle exceptions here
    MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
}
}
```

And here's what the stored procedure would look like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddParent]
    @IP          NVARCHAR(50),
    @Parent      INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO YourTable (IP,ParentID) VALUES (IP,null);
    SET @Parent = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
```